# Access parent jsp from child jsp which is compiled in iframe

Tags: jsp, iframe

Here is my problem:

I have a JSP that is creating an iframe and loading content from a child jsp. The child jsp is decided during runtime. I need to access the parent JSP from the child, and change a variable value there. Kindly suggest a way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My requirement was to change a parent JSP element from child JSP and I didn't want to wait till the child JSP loaded. The child was invoked through .

So, in the parent, I hid the element, and in child i did this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.parent.$(".classOfSubElement").text("Something");
        window.parent.$(".classOfHhiddenParentElement").show();
    </script>
</head>
```